# foreach loop only getting 1 item?

Tags: c#, sql

I have added a FOREACH loop to my code and I want it to loop around how many selected items I have. If I select 2, when I debug it has a count of 2, but gets the information from the first selected item twice.

```
if(result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    int userid = viewuser.AuditUserId;
    var data = (string)null;

    foreach (var item in dgAllocate.SelectedItems)
    {
       data = transaction.TransactionId.ToString();
       sp.InsertInformationToAuditTasks(userid, data, "15000", DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

This is my loop and it suppost to get the different TransactionIds from the different selected items.

[image]

As you can see i selected multiple ones and it brings out the same id?

EDIT:

```
cAuditTransactionsEntity transaction = _TransactionId as cAuditTransactionsEntity;
```

That's how I am defining transaction.

Comment: Have you debugged? What is value of `dgAllocate.SelectedItems`?

Comment: You use `item` to hold the `selectedItems`, but you never print it or do anything to that.

Comment: please paste intire relevant code. where does "transaction" changes?
the loop inside doesn't change its value..

Comment: @Satpal Yes, the selecteditems comes out with how many I selected which is correct, when I hover over 'data =' both times they are the same?

Comment: Are you using `item` inside the `foreach` loop?

Comment: @J.A.I.L. No, Where do i neeed to place 'Item'?

Comment: What is the value of `transaction` and how do you expect it to change with each iteration without doing anything to it?

Comment: @Mathew I added the value of transaction, and I don't understand what I need to do with that.

Comment: How `item` related to `transaction` ? Accourding to `item` u have to get `transaction` and then by `TransactionId` u can insert multiple data for multiple `items`.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Item holds what I selected in dgallocate as I have just opened it up but I don't know the code that goes in the foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume that `item` is of type `cAuditTransactionsEntity` and then u can get `data` for multile items like this

```
   if(result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
   {
     int userid = viewuser.AuditUserId;
     var data = (string)null;

     foreach (var item in dgAllocate.SelectedItems)
     {
       // Here u have to get cAuditTransactionsEntity by item object
       data = (item as cAuditTransactionsEntity).TransactionId.ToString();
       sp.InsertInformationToAuditTasks(userid, data, "15000", DateTime.Now);
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

You're updating the value of "item" with each iteration but not using it.

You're assigning "data" from "transaction" which you're not updating:

```
data = transaction.TransactionId.ToString();
```

Comment: How do I update data from the first value to the second?

Comment: Pure guess: does each item have a reference to a transaction?

Comment: When I debug and hover over 'Item' its showing it does have a reference to it.

Comment: try: data = item.Transaction.TransactionId.ToString() (check capitalisation of property transaction on item)

Comment: Check capitalisation of "item" too - the instance variable in the snippet above is named "item" perhaps there is also a class named "Item"

Comment: Tried changing the name and the same properties appear :/

Comment: Which "item" did you hover over when you saw the reference to "transaction"?

Comment: When I hover over item in the brackets and open it up it comes out with the tranactionID which is correct? but from here I don't know the code I need to add inside the foreach loop

Comment: Do you know what type you expect item to be?

Comment: it need to be a string if that's what your asking?

Comment: is item a string which contains the transaction id?

Answer (score 2):

You are never using the 'item' variable being set in the loop. I presume you need to use this in some way to change the data. Where is transaction defined ? It is not being modified in the loop at all.

Comment: I added when I am defining transaction, it is basically calling a virtual table in my C#.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the data from the item, not the transaction id from your transaction:

```
foreach (var item in dgAllocate.SelectedItems)
{
   var data = item.TransactionId.ToString();
   sp.InsertInformationToAuditTasks(userid, data, "15000", DateTime.Now);
}
```

Check your code:

```
var data = (string)null;
```

will give a cast exception. Move the declaration inside your foreach loop.

Comment: When I change my code to call the item like you said I get 'ToString' and the other 3 options. I cant call my property name?

Comment: This didn't work as item doesn't have a reference to the transacionID of the selected item?